# Questions about vuex dynamic registration module causes all vue components to refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to create a new vue component, before create i need to invoke store.registerModule()，but it causes all vue components destory and recreate. The same is true of store.unregisterModule(). How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but here is my solution to register dynamically.

```js
// if no module or already registered in state, stop.
if (!module || this.$store.state[module]) {
  return
}

// else, register
this.$store.registerModule(module, {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    ...
  }
}
```